# PowerShell script for returning groups assigned to application

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, adgroup

Is there a better way to do this? I want to return the AD groups that are assigned to an Azure AD application.  I can find a lot of information on looking at the assigned roles, but not the groups.

The code below, looks at all AD groups first and then ultimately checks the application to see if they are applied.  Is there a way to check the application directly?

```
$ApplicationName = "<NameOfApp>"

$ADGroupList = Get-AzureADGroup -All 1 | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName.Contains('<search string>') } #Find ALL groups that contain search text

#Loop through each group in list and output ObjectID, ResourceDisplayName, and PrincipalDisplayName for each that is assigned to the specified application
ForEach ($group in $ADGroupList){  #Each group in list
    Get-AzureADGroupAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $group.ObjectID | Where-Object { $_.ResourceDisplayName -eq $ApplicationName }
}
```

Comment: I've not needed to do this use case, so, unsure. However, if you can do it in the Azure GUI, then look at the property particulars and put that in your code. If it is not there, then that means an underlying API is needed, which MS may not have exposed. So, you need to research that or hit up your MS Azure rep.

Comment: Do you have a chance to look into my answer? If it is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The cmdlet for checking a service principal application role assignment is [Get-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadserviceapproleassignment?view=azureadps-2.0).

A sample here:

```
Get-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $applicationObjectId | Where-Object{$_.PrincipalType -eq "Group"}
```